# Iterate obect in view, JSON hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parsing, loops, hash

I have parsed the JSON api externally and now it is a hash as such:

```
["statement", {"generated"=>"2015-01-11", "due"=>"2015-01-25", "period"=>{"from"=>"2015-01-26", "to"=>"2015-02-25"}}
```

I used:

```
require 'json/pure'
require 'open-uri'

 def index
   content = open("MY_URL").read
   @hash = JSON.parse content
   render @hash
 end
```

and this gives me the whole hash output on the view using:

```
<% @hash.each do |hash| %>
<%= hash %>
<% end %>
```

So lets say I wanted to print generated, due and period, separately, how would I do this. I'm so close I know it.

array:

```
 ["statement", {"generated"=>"2015-01-11", "due"=>"2015-01-25", "period"=>{"from"=>"2015-01-26", "to"=>"2015-02-25"}}] ["total", 136.03] ["package", {"subscriptions"=>[{"type"=>"tv", "name"=>"Variety with Movies", "cost"=>50.0}, {"type"=>"talk", "name"=>"Talk Anytime", "cost"=>5.0}, {"type"=>"broadband", "name"=>"Fibre Unlimited", "cost"=>16.4}], "total"=>71.4}] ["callCharges", {"calls"=>[{"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}], "total"=>59.64}] ["Store", {"rentals"=>[{"title"=>"50 Shades of Grey", "cost"=>4.99}], "buyAndKeep"=>[{"title"=>"That's what she said", "cost"=>9.99}, {"title"=>"Broke back mountain", "cost"=>9.99}], "total"=>24.97}] [:prefixes, ["tasks", "application"]] [:template, "index"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you need to extract the values from the hash to print them individually.

The first piece of code you wrote is actually an array, not a hash.  The first element of the array is a String and the second is a hash.  The first thing you want to do is create a variable with the hash only, removing the string:

```
<% @hash_values = @hash[1] %>
```

With this hash, you want to extract the values of 'generated', 'due' and 'period' by looking them up by their keys:

```
<%= @hash_values['generated'] %>
<%= @hash_values['due'] %>
<%= @hash_values['period'] %>
```

In the case of 'period', the result is a hash.  You many want to extract the individual values a bit more for formatting, e.g.:

```
<%= @hash_values['period']['from'] %> to <%= @hash_values['period']['to'] %>
```

Comment: everything is making sense to me, however I get an error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: can you copy and paste the line of code that threw the error?

Comment: <%= @hash_values['generated'] %>  Application trace:    app/views/tasks/index.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_tasks_index_html_erb___299787190_93358320'
app/views/tasks/index.html.erb:1:in `each'
app/views/tasks/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks_index_html_erb___299787190_93358320'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:13:in `index'

Comment: can you print out hash_values, and resend the first piece of code?  Not sure what the first piece of code in your question (the one I told you to extract @hash_values from) was because you didn't close the array.

Comment: My mistake, I didnt see the array properly, the array is actually really big. it is closed off right at the end with its prefixes present too. I have edited the code please take a look.

Comment: you've got a series of arrays there without a delimiter.  why don't you isolate the first array (with "statement" and the hash) and then we can work from there.